# ASP.Net Custom Validator failed ,form gets submitted

Tags: asp.net, telerik, datetimepicker, customvalidator

I have made a form in which there are two RAD DateTimePicker Controls . One is for Start-DateTime and other is for End Date Time. Inside Custom Validator, I have Compared the Date Time Picked So far and hence made it valid or invalid accordingly its Server Validate event  code goes like this.

```
protected void CustomValidator1_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args) {
    if (rdpEndDate.SelectedDate < rdpStartDate.SelectedDate) {
        args.IsValid = false;
    } else {
        args.IsValid = true;
    }
}
```

Its Design Code goes like this.

```
<telerik:RadDateTimePicker ID="rdpStartDate" runat="server" AutoPostBackControl="Both" onselecteddatechanged="rdpStartDate_SelectedDateChanged">
    <TimeView CellSpacing="-1" Culture="en-IN">
    </TimeView>
    <TimePopupButton HoverImageUrl="" ImageUrl="" />
    <Calendar UseColumnHeadersAsSelectors="False" UseRowHeadersAsSelectors="False" ViewSelectorText="x">
    </Calendar>
    <DateInput AutoPostBack="True" DateFormat="dd-MM-yyyy" DisplayDateFormat="dd-MM-yyyy">
    </DateInput>
    <DatePopupButton HoverImageUrl="" ImageUrl="" />
</telerik:RadDateTimePicker>
<asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text=" To" CssClass="h_text"></asp:Label>
<telerik:RadDateTimePicker ID="rdpEndDate" runat="server" onselecteddatechanged="rdpEndDate_SelectedDateChanged" AutoPostBackControl="Both">
    <TimeView CellSpacing="-1" Culture="en-IN"></TimeView>

    <TimePopupButton ImageUrl="" HoverImageUrl=""></TimePopupButton>

    <Calendar UseRowHeadersAsSelectors="False" UseColumnHeadersAsSelectors="False" ViewSelectorText="x"></Calendar>

    <DateInput DisplayDateFormat="dd-MM-yyyy" DateFormat="dd-MM-yyyy" AutoPostBack="True"></DateInput>

    <DatePopupButton ImageUrl="" HoverImageUrl=""></DatePopupButton>
</telerik:RadDateTimePicker>
```

Validator Source Code in designer is like this.

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="rdpEndDate"
                    ErrorMessage="End Date Cant be Before Start Date" 
                    OnServerValidate="CustomValidator1_ServerValidate" SetFocusOnError="True" 
                    ValidateEmptyText="True" ValidationGroup="submit">End Date Cant be Before Start Date</asp:CustomValidator>
```

I want to ask that even when custom validator fails, My form gets submitted with faulty values. What can be the reason? How can I avoid that?

Comment: set validationgroup for customvalidator

Comment: @Saritha.S.R I have already done that as mentioned in the code above.

Comment: Did you set same validationgroup in button also

Comment: Yes.. I added the same validation group to button also.

Answer (score 1):

With Server validator Event like:

```
protected void CustomValidator1_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args) {
    if (rdpEndDate.SelectedDate < rdpStartDate.SelectedDate) {
        args.IsValid = false;
    } else {
        args.IsValid = true;
    }
}
```

You have to check on your server event as well like:(For example if you are using your validator with button click then)

```
protected void btn_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    if (Page.IsValid) 
    {
         Response.Write("Page is valid.");
    }
    else 
    {
         Response.Write("Page is not valid!");
    }
}
```

**My suggestion:** Telerik has a good client side support as well so I suggest you to use client side validation of custom validator.

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="rdpEndDate"
                    ErrorMessage="End Date Cant be Before Start Date" 
                    ClientValidationFunction="CheckDates" 
                    SetFocusOnError="True" 
                    ValidateEmptyText="True" ValidationGroup="submit">End Date Cant be Before Start Date</asp:CustomValidator>
```

then in Javascript:

```
function CheckDates(sender, args)
{
    var cltRdpEndDate= $find("<%=rdpEndDate.ClientID %>");
    var cltRdpStartDate= $find("<%=rdpStartDate.ClientID %>");    

    if(cltRdpEndDate.get_dateInput().get_selectedDate()< cltRdpStartDate.get_dateInput().get_selectedDate())//if your condtion fails here
    {
        args.IsValid = false;
        return;
    }
        args.IsValid = true;
}
```